# How to "complete" objects returned by Dapper?

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I'm using Dapper for mapping results of SQL queries to different types. It works pretty good, but I need one thing more: a handler which will perform some post-processing of objects when they are already de-serialized. For instance:

```
var persons = await conn.QueryAsync<Models.User>("Select * from [User]");
var companies = await conn.QueryAsync<Models.Company>("Select * from [Company]");
```

This interceptor should grab each completed instance of models do do this:

```
if(obj is IChangeTracking ict)
{
    ict.AcceptChanges();
}
```

I'd like to have this functionality standard for all models and avoid registering of de-serializers for each model. Is there a way for that?

I tried to find a solution investigating Dapper code, but to be honest I do not have much experience in c#.

Comment: How would they even _have_ changes to accept?

Comment: Fildor, Dapper sets properties after instantiation a model. Thus object becomes 'changed'. My goal is to reset changes and have it clear. Only changes made later should change status of object.

Comment: Haven't worked with dapper, but AcceptChanges feels wrong to me for that purpose. Honestly, I am taken aback a little because I thought Dapper didn't even have change tracking.

Comment: Are you using some addon to dapper?

Comment: Fildor, you are right that Dapper itself does not have change tracking. I looked at several several side projects like Dapper-Extensions or Dapper.Contrib. Seems they also do not have tracking of changes. When I update just one field in model then they still produce "update" query with full set of fields. Project which I'm working expected to be good for high load, so I cannot use heavy tools like Entity framework. I must choose a micro-ORM and slightly improve it.